# Designing your own button in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to draw the following picture with each circle segment consisting of 3 buttons which can be clicked.

[image: See picture]

I've copied code from this forum, but when I try to use it, I get an error message and the code will not compile. Tried various versions (latest one printed), but none work. What am I doing wrong? Also, will the integers i and j be passed on to the call of the class CustomShapeButton?

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct ContentView: View {

    static let segmentCount = 4
    static let circleCount = 4

    var i: Int = 0
    var j: Int = 0
    var NewButtons: CustomShapeButton

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(1..<ContentView.circleCount){ j in
                ForEach(1..<ContentView.segmentCount){ i in
                    NewButtons = CustomShapeButton()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


class CustomShapeButton: UIButton {

    lazy var pantsShapeBezierPath: UIBezierPath = {
        // Crate new path
        let path = UIBezierPath()

        var r = CGFloat(75.0)
        r = CGFloat(50.0 + (CGFloat(j) - 1.0) * 50.0)
        let center_x = CGFloat(200.0)
        let center_y = CGFloat(200.0)
        var arc_start = CGFloat(45.0 * CGFloat(Double.pi) / 180.0)
        arc_start = CGFloat((45.0 + (CGFloat(i) - 1.0) * 90.0)) * CGFloat(Double.pi) / 180.0

        let arc_length = CGFloat(90.0 * CGFloat(Double.pi) / 180.0)
        let arc_width = CGFloat(45.0)
        let line0Target_x = center_x + r * CGFloat(cos(Double(arc_start)))
        let line0Target_y = center_y + r * CGFloat(sin(Double(arc_start)))
        let line1Target_x = center_x + (r + arc_width) * CGFloat(cos(Double(arc_start + arc_length)))
        let line1Target_y = center_x + (r + arc_width) * CGFloat(sin(Double(arc_start + arc_length)))

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: line0Target_x, y: line0Target_y))
        path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: center_x, y: center_y), radius: r, startAngle: Angle(radians: Double(arc_start)), endAngle: Angle(radians: Double(arc_start + arc_length)), clockwise: false)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: line1Target_x, y: line1Target_y))
        path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: center_x, y: center_y), radius: (r + arc_width), startAngle: Angle(radians: Double(arc_start + arc_length)), endAngle: Angle(radians: Double(arc_start)), clockwise: true)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: line0Target_x, y: line0Target_y))
        path.close()

        return path
    }()

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)

        // Set shape filling color
        UIColor.red.setFill()

        // Fill the shape
        pantsShapeBezierPath.fill()
    }

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {

        // Handling touch events

        if (pantsShapeBezierPath.contains(point)) {
            return self

        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're missing some *key* things in your question. First, what's the build error you're getting? Keep in mind that it may be misleading. Second, where's the SwiftUI representable? If you are using a `UIButton`, you *cannot* simply instantiate it in a SwiftUI `View`. (I'm thinking this is the main issue here.) Finally, have you tried using `CustomShapeButton` in a "Storyboard" project?

Comment: The build error is the following: "Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable", indeed not very helpful.

Comment: As for the use of UIButton in SwiftUI, I naively thought that by including UIKit that would be possible. But if it is not, then the question becomes: how can I define a certain shape, and convert that to a button in SwiftUI? Finally, the picture was drawn using SwiftUI, but I'm stuck with assigning the arc segments to a shape and changing various properties of those segments like color and border.

Comment: Just saw your comments. Two recommendations. First, regards to the build error, there's been many questions with issues like this and almost always it get down to (a) commenting out just about everything in the view then 9b) slowly reintroduce your code to find the *real* line of code causing the issue. It even happens sometimes that the actual error is exposed by doing this....

Comment: Second, - and this is just a guess - you may not be able to do what you want in SwiftUI (yet). A SwiftUI `View` can draw bezier paths ( https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-uibezierpath-and-cgpath-in-swiftui ) but I'm unsure that will accomplish everything you need. Even if you have it working in UIKit  there are a few limitations with representables, *despite* Apple's claims that "everything is a view" (hint - show me where `some View` is part of a representable). In the end I went with notifications to my model, before I trashed using SwiftUI at all.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. You just need to implement the button style first then use it. This result is 9 buttons. I would suggest having 9 functions for each button and not using the same one.

```
struct CustomShapeButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    var j: Int
    var i: Int
    var fillColor: Color

    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Path { path in
                var r = CGFloat(75.0)
                r = CGFloat(50.0 + (CGFloat(self.j) - 1.0) * 50.0)
                let center_x = CGFloat(200.0)
                let center_y = CGFloat(200.0)
                var arc_start = CGFloat(45.0 * CGFloat(Double.pi) / 180.0)
                arc_start = CGFloat((45.0 + (CGFloat(self.i) - 1.0) * 90.0)) * CGFloat(Double.pi) / 180.0
                let arc_length = CGFloat(90.0 * CGFloat(Double.pi) / 180.0)
                let arc_width = CGFloat(45.0)
                let line0Target_x = center_x + r * CGFloat(cos(Double(arc_start)))
                let line0Target_y = center_y + r * CGFloat(sin(Double(arc_start)))
                let line1Target_x = center_x + (r + arc_width) * CGFloat(cos(Double(arc_start + arc_length)))
                let line1Target_y = center_x + (r + arc_width) * CGFloat(sin(Double(arc_start + arc_length)))

                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: line0Target_x, y: line0Target_y))
                path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: center_x, y: center_y), radius: r, startAngle: Angle(radians: Double(arc_start)), endAngle: Angle(radians: Double(arc_start + arc_length)), clockwise: false)
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: line1Target_x, y: line1Target_y))
                path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: center_x, y: center_y), radius: (r + arc_width), startAngle: Angle(radians: Double(arc_start + arc_length)), endAngle: Angle(radians: Double(arc_start)), clockwise: true)
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: line0Target_x, y: line0Target_y))
                path.closeSubpath()
            }.fill(self.fillColor)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    static let segmentCount = 4
    static let circleCount = 4

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(1..<Self.circleCount) { j in
                ForEach(1..<Self.segmentCount) { i in
                    Button(action: {
                        print("I was clicked")
                    }) {
                        Text("") // Just a placeholder
                    }.buttonStyle(CustomShapeButtonStyle(j: j, i: i, fillColor: Color(red: 177/255, green: 152/255, blue: 177/255)))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is mixing both UIKit and SwiftUI in an improper way. You can't do this in a `body` statement:

```
NewButtons = CustomShapeButton()
```

Everything inside of the `body` function has to be a `View`. This is an assignment statement.

Next, `CustomShapeButton` is a `UIButton` subclass. You can't use that here, either. If you want to use this random internet code (which I do not suggest), you will have to wrap it inside of a `UIViewRepresentable`. Instead, consider following Apple's guide on how to create custom path-based `View`s.

https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/drawing-paths-and-shapes

Once you can draw the shapes that you want, wrap it in a `Button`:

```swift
Button(action: { /* do your action */ }) {
    CircularCutoutShape()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried your solution on the mentioned "drawing-paths-and-shapes" guide. When I try to wrap the badge-shape in a button, I get the error message: "Cannot convert value of type '() -> GeometryReader<some View>' to expected argument type 'PrimitiveButtonStyleConfiguration' ". For reference, I updated the code in the "Badge.swift" file. Does this mean that buttons with complex shapes are not possible in SwiftUI?